# Is it possible to show an empty region in a Prism application?

Tags: wpf, prism

I registered one view to the appropriate region, but the view automatically displays. I would like to register it to a region but not display it by default. Is this possible? I'm new to Prism. Here is the line that I use to register:

```
regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion<DepartmentView>(RegionNames.MainRegion);
```

Comment: regions are empty by default until you explicitly insert things into them.  not sure what the question is here...

Comment: I tried to clarify the question.

Comment: So how about not calling that line of code until you want the view to show?

Comment: So registering and unregistering is equivalent to showing and not showing? I thought you're supposed to register views with regions at the beginning and then use some other code to display and hide? I guess I'm trying to grasp what registering a view really means in a Prism application.

Answer (score 1):

The first View you register into the region will be shown by default.  You will need to register each view into the region if you want to be able to Navigate to the View in the region.  There's not too much context to your question, but if you want it to remove the view that's displayed, you can call "Deactivate".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.region.deactivate(v=pandp.50).aspx

```
object activeRegion = regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion].ActiveViews.FirstOrDefault();

if (activeRegion != null)
{
    regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion].Deactivate(activeRegion);
}
```